# What does A stand for? liminf proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I am trying to learn limsup and liminf and got stuck reading the problem below:

For an arbitrary sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\},$ prove that:

**a) If there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $n$ greater than $k$ the inequality $a_{n} \leq A$ holds, then $\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} \leq A$**

**I cant figure out what A stands for.** The book does not mention A anywhere else. As an attempt to try and figure out what "A" is i checked the solution(proof), which goes like this:

**Proof:**
If the set $S$ of the limit points of $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$ is empty, then $\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=$ $-\infty \leq A .$ Now assume that $\mathbf{S}$ is nonempty. since $\mathbf{S}$ is closed (see Problem 2.4.9 ) , sup $S=\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=L \in$ S. It follows from the definition of a limit point that there exists a subsequence $\left\{a_{n_{k}}\right\}$ converging to $L .$ Therefore, for any $\varepsilon>0,$ there is $k_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
L-\varepsilon<a_{n_{k}} \leq A \quad \text { for } \quad k>k_{0}
$$
since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we get $L \leq A .$

The book also does not explicitly states the definition of $\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}$, but i am assuming it means $$
\overline{\lim }\left\{x_{n}\right\}=\inf \left\{y_{n}:\quad n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$ where $$
y_{n}=\sup \left\{x_{k}: k \geq n\right\}
$$

The book "Problems in Mathematical Analysis I" by W. J. Kaczor and M.T. Nowak

Comment: $A$ is simply some real number (unless $\infty$ is allowed, in which case it is some extended real number).

Comment: But isn't A related in some way to the boundedness of the sequence? Because he writes $a_{n} \leq A$

Comment: The authors are just being slightly concise. $A$ is a placeholder for some constant. In other words, the half of the sentence could be read as "...the inequality $a_n \le A$ holds for some particular real number $A$, then ..."

Comment: $A\in\mathbb{R}\cup\pm\infty$

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong So the quantifier in question is "there exists". Is that right? He is not saying that "given any real number A", $a_{n} \leq A$, correct?

Comment: He is saying: If $A$ is some (extended) real number, and there is some $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_n\le A$ for each $n>k$, then $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\le A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Super Nice! Quick question: Why does one have to consider the extended real numbers in such situation?

Comment: @Lucas: One doesn’t, but it does no harm and causes no extra difficulty.